# How to repair damaged lining paper for painting?

Tags: repair, repainting, wallpaper

I've stripped some old wallpaper in order to paint the walls and discovered painted lining paper beneath. I'm happy to paint over this paper as it's mainly in good condition (and I don't want to deal with whatever the plaster is like below). However it has numerous holes from old fittings (up to about 20mm) and some tears and scuffing where the surface of the paper is exposing the fluffy innards of the paper.

Other than stripping the paper and plastering the wall, what's the recommended approach for repairing the papered surface well enough for painting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly this in one room in our house. I simply treated it like a normal wall, filling the holes and sanding until flush.

For the scratches, you could probably just paint over with a 50/50 paint/water mix to seal the fibres, and then sand and fill as necessary when dry.
I find [Quick-Dry PolyFilla](https://www.diy.com/departments/polycell-quick-dry-ready-mixed-filler-330g/196415_BQ.prd) perfect for light surface scratches. It dries so fast that you can do two or three fill & sand operations in about half-an-hour.

**NB**:
Make sure you've sugar-soaped the wall really well, as any residue wallpaper-paste may cause the paint to blister.

Comment: I was considering a fine surface filler, but was unsure that was proper. Glad to hear this worked out. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Please upvote helpful answers thanks are great but upvotes and accepting are how we say thanks, accepting a good answer you click on the green check , saying thanks but waiting for a better answer click on the up arrow.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I know this. I have been a StackExchange user for 10 years. Until I have *tried* the solution given I cannot accept it as true/correct. Hence why I thanked the poster in the interim. I will accept the answer when I'm ready to do so.